# Removing first n character's from text file in Bash Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, char

I am trying to remove the first N characters from a text file and whats Important is that
it is done NOT LINE BY LINE.

Currently this code that I have written deletes 'i' number of chars from EACH Line. But I want to delete from the whole text.

```
for FILE in *; 
    do  x=$(wc -c < "$FILE"); for ((i=1; i <= $x; ++i));
            do sed "s/^.\{$i\}//" $FILE > $i; 
        done;
done;
```

for example I have this xml file in the directory xml/root.xml

```
<ticket id="usa-001" REFUND="NO" TEST="TEST">
        <airline>Us Airlines</airline>
        <emptytag id="usa-001" REFUND="NO" TEST="TEST"/>
        <preis>30</preis><seat>
            <allseats>120</allseats>
</ticket>
```

What I want is deleting the first N chars and saving it into a new file. lets say 5 so it would be

```
et id="usa-001" REFUND="NO" TEST="TEST">
        <airline>Us Airlines</airline>
        <emptytag id="usa-001" REFUND="NO" TEST="TEST"/>
        <preis>30</preis><seat>
            <allseats>120</allseats>
</ticket>
```

Comment: what should happen if you're looking to remove 100 characters but there are only 35 characters in the 1st line? do you continue removing characters until 100 have been removed? do you count the linefeed (`\n`) (and potential carriage return - `\r`) at the end of a line as part of the 100 characters?

Comment: To skip `$n` characters, use `dd bs=1 skip="$n"`

Comment: It's good that you added an example, but since you said `whats Important is that it is done NOT LINE BY LINE` your example would have been much better for testing a potential solution with if the text to remove wasn't all on 1 line. With the given example, scripts that do and scripts that don't do what you want would produce the same output so we can't tell if they actually work or not by testing with your example. Something to think about for next time.

Comment: Btw, your script looks like you might want to create separate files for the concatenation of various strings from all of your input files - if so, a shell loop calling sed in a second nested loop would be immensely slow vs calling awk once. Post a new question if you want help with that bigger problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU sed:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/^.{5}//' root.xml > 5
```

```
$ cat 5
et id="usa-001" REFUND="NO" TEST="TEST">
        <airline>Us Airlines</airline>
        <emptytag id="usa-001" REFUND="NO" TEST="TEST"/>
        <preis>30</preis><seat>
            <allseats>120</allseats>
</ticket>
```

if you want to remove up to 5 chars in files that have less than 5 then use `{1,5}` instead of `{5}`.

Comment: `-z` isn't strictly slurping input file, it changes record separator to ASCII NUL, so something like `printf 'a\0b\0c\0d3567\n3223\n'` won't change... but that's likely not a problem for OP given the sample..

Comment: sed is a tool for processing text and by POSIX definition text files must not contain NULs.

Comment: Thank you. I also have a small question. If i want to do the same thing but the LAST N chars, What would the code look like ? basically reverse of this question.

Comment: `^.{5}` -> `.{5}$`

Answer (score 5):

If you really just want to filter out the first n characters of a file, the tool you want is `dd` which allows you to specify the number of blocks to skip.  If you want a block size of 1, specify that with `bs`.  For example, to skip the first 2 characters of the input file, use:

```
$ echo foobarbaz | dd bs=1 skip=2 2> /dev/null
obarbaz
```

You can specify an input file with `if`, but it's probably simpler to redirect.  `dd` writes a bunch of diagnostics to stderr, and the output redirection is just there to suppress those messages.  This will be slow as dirt since the block size is so small, but (if you have a dd which supports this) you can be much faster than `sed` with:

```
dd iflag=skip_bytes skip=5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `tail`:

```bash
# display from 4th byte
# in other words, remove first 3 bytes
$ printf 'apple\nbanana\nfig\ncherry\n' | tail -c +4
le
banana
fig
cherry
```

Comment: Be warned that this work as intended with ASCII files, it might malfunction when processing UTF-8 files.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

***For single Input_file:***

```
awk -i inplace -v RS='^.{5}' -v ORS='' 'END{print}'  Input_file
```

***For multiple Input_file(s)*** with GNU `awk`: Using `ENDFILE` function here which will process all lines at the end of each Input_file as names suggests.

```
awk -i inplace -v RS='^.{5}' -v ORS='' 'ENDFILE{print}' *
```

Answer (score 2):

With `cut`

```
n=5; cut -c$n- file.txt
```

---

It looks like you want to save each line in a file.

```
n=5; cut -c$n- file.txt | awk '{print $0 > NR}'
```

---

```
n=5; cut -c$n- file.txt | awk '{print $0 > NR; exit}'
```

Comment: This works but it deletes one char from EVERY line. I want to delete n chars from the begin

Comment: @Ali, updated the answer for your requirements

Answer (score 1):

You know, you can also use `hexdump`:

```
hexdump -s 5 -ve '/1 "%c"' inputfile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something hacky and ugly like this -

```
awk 'BEGIN{ left=100 } { if (left>0) { len=length($0); if (len<left) { left-=len+1; next } else {  print substr($0,left); len=0; next } } else print $0 }' infile
```

Don't, please... Use Ed's `sed` instead.

You could use `Perl` -

```
perl -e 'seek(STDIN,100,0) && print <>' < infile # simpler
perl -e '$/=undef; open(my $fh,$ARGV[0]); seek($fh,100,0) && print <$fh>' infile # cleaner
```

but William's `dd` works on binaries without requiring any code...

```
dd bs=1 skip=100 < infile > outfile
```

and Sundeep's is probably most *on target* for text files if your version understands the `+` option -

```
tail -c +101 infile # start at byte 101, having skipped the first 100
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know it's `ASCII` :

> ```
> jot -s '' 27 | gsed -zE 's/.{15}/&\n/g; s/[\n]+$/\n/g'
> ```

```
123456789101112
131415161718192
021222324252627
```

> ```
> mawk 5 RS='^.....' ORS=
> ```

```
6789101112
131415161718192
021222324252627
```

Assuming it's conforming `UTF-8` text, then then this should kinda work to clean up to 5 unicode chars of any sort up front, including newlines :

> ```
>   printf '%s' "${test_input}" | gnu-wc -lcm
> ```

- ```
  ꜜ&$Ꝡ*&꟠.(ꢔ2*ꥴ6,꩸:.ꮘ>0곌B2긌F4꽐J6낐N8뇄R:다V<돨Z>듈^@땼bB뗼fD뙀jF
  ```
- ```
   0      54      90
  ```

> ```
> mawk2 'BEGIN { 
>     FS = "^"  (_=(_="([\\000-\\177]|" \
>          "[\\302-\\364][\\200-\\277]+)")(_=(_)_)_ 
>
>    OFS = ORS =__="" 
>    _+=_^= RS = "^$" } __!= $(NF *=_==NF )' | gnu-wc -lcm
> ```

- ```
   0      49      81
  ```